# Ansible - check for a list of items

Tags: ansible

I have a list of strings that I expect in some command's output. How can I create an ansible script that tests and - in case one or several of the entries is not contained - executes a task?

So my ansible script might look like:

```
vars:
  musthave:
    - value1
    - value2
tasks:
- name: Check the configured values
  command: "cat configfile"
  register: current_configuration
  changed_when: false

- set a variable if one or more of the musthave's are missing in current_configuration.stdout
  ...

- name: Execute task to reconfigure system
  command: "reconfigure..."
  when: true = variable
```

So is there something like

```
variable = false
for s in musthave:
    if not s in current_configuration.stdout:
        variable |= true
```

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Comment: Actually I am going to check whether enough alternative subject names are contained in a certificate. So when issuing 'openssl x509 -in certificatefile -noout -text' I can see the alternative names. So now I want to compare whether the expected names from the list variable are contained. I guess the concise format does not matter, does it?

Comment: It would probably be better to use the [community.crypto.x509_certificate module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html) instead of calling a command, because it can return the names in a format that is easy to work with. It can also manage and renew your certificates from Let's Encrypt and some other providers.

Comment: I'll have a look, thank you. This may solve my current issue but does not anwer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may be easier to resolve using the suggested community module I preferred a solution that does not imply more libraries to be installed. Here is the solution I came up with.

My original request was looking to check for existence of specific values that may appear somewhere in the command's output. Preparing a list for difference to work is a disadvantage, the side effect is that you can calculate the difference in both directions.

So now I can not only check for missing entries but also for those that are too much.

```
- name: print hostvars
  debug:
    var: hostvars[{{ ansible_host }}]['certificate_domains']

- name: print certificate
  delegate_to: silver.fritz.box
  command: "openssl x509 -in /home/hiran/homeserver.crt -noout -text"
  register: certificate

- name: grab subject's common name and alternative names
  set_fact:
    commonName: "{{ certificate.stdout | regex_search('Subject.*CN\\s=\\s([\\.a-zA-Z]+)', '\\1') }}"
    altNames: "{{ certificate.stdout | regex_findall('DNS:([\\.a-zA-Z]+)') }}"
- name: prepare the lists so they can be subtracted from each other
  set_fact:
    contained: "{{ (commonName + altNames) | unique }}"
    musthave: "{{ hostvars[{{ ansible_host }}]['certificate_domains'] | unique }}"
- name: calculate differences
  set_fact:
    missing: "{{ musthave | difference(contained) }}"
    toomuch: "{{ contained | difference(musthave) }}"

- name: show difference
  debug:
    msg: Something is wrong
  when: (missing | length)>0 or (toomuch | length)>0
```